# How much time does the cursorMark is available on solr server

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

Using cursorMark we can overcome deep paging; so far so good. I have a question

If that is the case then for how much time is this mark live on the server.

If there are different unique requests for cursorMark=* then it might take all the server RAM right? Is there any way we can destroy the mark if it is no longer used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CursorMark [does not require server state](http://heliosearch.org/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/). It's just a value referring to some internal information.

So, there should be no memory impact from using it with multiple clients.

Comment: if cursorMark don't need server state does it need to compute the results every time we query.

Comment: I don't believe so. It just skips until the CursorMark's internal position and then continues from there. Like a specialized filter.